# Difference in ways of deleting object array

Tags: c++, arrays, object

Is there some difference in the following deletions of object array?

The first way:

```
MyClass **obj = new MyClass*[NUM];
for (int i=0; i<NUM; i++) obj[i] = new MyClass(val);
obj[0]->method();
for (int i=0; i<NUM; i++) delete obj[i]; /// Deletion1
delete obj;                              /// Deletion1
```

The second way:

```
MyClass **obj = new MyClass*[NUM];
for (int i=0; i<NUM; i++) obj[i] = new MyClass(val);
obj[0]->method();
delete[] obj;                            /// Deletion2
obj = 0x0;                               /// Deletion2
```

Both ways are workable and look similar in debugger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there a delete\[\] in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694333/why-is-there-a-delete-in-c)

Comment: "obj = 0x0; /// Deletion2" A great example of a comments being lies!

Comment: The correct answer is not at all. If you have to delete something manually, you've done it wrong.

Comment: Cris, I don't think so. Explanations, like you indicated, weren't enough for me.

Comment: Johnsyweb, it was rather a border flag, that a real comment. Clearly, the samples are investigating things like homework.

Comment: GMan, it isn't a excerpt of big industrial code with proper behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, you are explicitly calling the destructor for each object pointed to by members of the allocated array. Then you are deleting the array of pointers (which should really be `delete[]` because you allocated it as an array, but in practice for this example it probably doesn't matter).

In your second example, you are only deleting the array *of pointers*, which does not call the destructor for the pointed-to objects. The reason it doesn't is that you may have made copies of those pointers in other variables which the compiler doesn't necessarily know about.

If you were to create an array of *objects* and not *pointers*, like this:

```
MyClass *obj = new MyClass[NUM];
```

then the `delete[]` operator would automatically call the destructor for each of the `NUM` objects in the allocated array.

Comment: Thanks Greg. The reason, why I didn't want to use the way you suggested, was using non-def constructor, new MyClass(val). I was just confused with the deletion doubt.

Answer (score 4):

Both are incorrect.  The correct way would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) delete obj[i];
delete[] obj;
```

In the first way you show, you use `delete` to destroy an object allocated with `new[]`, which results in undefined behavior (if you use `new[]`, you must destroy the object using `delete[]`).

In the second way you show, you leak all of the pointers that you created in the first for loop.

If you use `std::vector` instead of dynamically allocated arrays and some type of smart pointer, then you don't have to worry about this in most code.